# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) for all CSS and JS files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I've uploaded files in recently bought domain and hosting server through cPanel. Files are in public_html folder.
There is an index.html which has links of CSS and JS files(CSS and JS files are in a folder, linking is okay I think because everything is working fine locally).
Site is opening but it is not loading CSS and JS files and showing this error for every CSS and JS file in page Inspect Console `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)`

Answer (score 0):

Permission issues:

```
chmod 777 your_resource_path/
```

Only in the development environment

Comment: I think 777 won't be a great idea anywhere. Any other solution?

Comment: chown -R www:www your_resource_path/